# No logs available for google cloud tasks?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-tasks

I have a very basic Flask app set up in a Google App Engine:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/<id>")
def hello(id):
    print("Got this id: {}".format(id))
    return "Hello World: {}".format(id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

I have enabled logging by running this in my terminal: `gcloud beta tasks queues update [QUEUE_ID] --log-sampling-ratio=1.0`

I am intentionally triggering an error by adding a POST request to my Flask endpoint. I see in my queue that this task retries many times, but when I click on the logs, I see this (task name and queue name intentionally modified for this screenshot):
[image]

I am expecting to see the error that I get from `gcloud app logs read`, which is:
`2019-11-18 16:27:59 default[20191118t002408]  "POST /example_task_handler" 405`

What am I doing wrong?

Update: I do see the logs I am looking for in the Google App Engine logs, but I don't see anything when I click on the logs for the individual failing POST Request task that gets retried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the issue was twofold.

1. I needed to use the python `logging` library, so I switched to `logging.info('Got this id: {}'.format(id))`
2. The default logging for python is warning and higher, so I needed to specify that it should print everything, which I did with:

```
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

(this works because DEBUG is the lowest logging level).

Answer (score 2):

1. Did you sub your queue's name ("my-queue-name") into for [QUEUE_ID] in `gcloud beta tasks queues update [QUEUE_ID] --log-sampling-ratio=1.0`?
2. In the tasks console, do you seen that there has been an attempt?
   [image]
3. Have you tried to load older or newer logs?
4. Are you using an App Engine target for your task?

Another way of finding logs is with the `Cloud Tasks Queue` selector in Stackdriver.
[image]

Comment: Yep! I ran it for my specific queue, and I do see entries for all my calls in the tasks console. I tried loading older and newer, and I am using an app engine target (which does exist) for my tasks. I see that the POST requests I try stay in the tasks console with multiple retries (as expected), and the GET requests work immediately (also as expected). It's just the logging that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Update: I do see the logs I am looking for in the GAE logs, but I don't see anything when I click on the logs for the individual failing POST Request task that gets retried (adding this to my question description as well)

Comment: When I try to recreate this, it does take from 5-20 secs after `load older logs` for logger to scan for the logs. Also did you enable logging before you created the task?

Comment: I've also updated my answer with another way to view logs.