How to be notified about a task failing all retries
I am currently learning how to use queues in GCP. I currently have a setup similar to this tutorial. https://medium.com/@rogiervandenberg/google-cloud-task-queues-on-gcp-with-google-cloud-functions-22eb80fe34ba

[graphic from site above which shows the main idea]
I want to change this to track failed functions so I can follow up on them to fix the crashes, so the new scheme will look something like this.

None of my searching has found a way to find anything about dead letter topics for cloud tasks or a way to be notified, but it seems like a obvious feature to have.
The only idea I have had so far is to make the function responsible for logging itself like below, but that seems clunkier then is typical of GCP.
try {
    // do stuff
} catch (error) {
    console.error("my_function() crashed with input: " + input)
    throw error
}

Edit: I HAVE tried the built in queue logging. I enabled it with this button in the logs tab

I do see the logs. Unfortunately, while it tells me about failed tasks, it does not give me information about what input failed, only a task id that I cannot translate to useful data.
Edit 1b: fixed spelling

As you have mentioned, Logging at cloud functions might be a better work around. Looks like  this similar issue also suggests implementing your own logging although app engine service is being discussed over there.I think for CF also you may have to do the same.

Have you managed to check above comment? Does it help you solve your issue? Or have you found any other solution?

@SupriyaBharti, Yes, I did check the linked question. It was a similar issue, but the answers were unhelpful. My setup is different in ways that mean that everything they tried was already done
In this answer by the original poster https://stackoverflow.com/a/58946655/20251918, the issue was that theydid not enable viewing the debug log level. I am using the google logs viewer, which enables that by defualt
this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58920248/20251918 is mostly about if it was setup correctly (more on this in the edit to the question)

@Supriya Bharti this is still not solved, did you have any additional info?

This issue seems to need more specific debugging and analysis and access to your environment. Hence I request you to file a support ticket by clicking here.

I ended up using the try catch method. Here is the code I used in cased anyone else needs to do the same thing, I am looking in the gcp logs directly to find out about issues, you could probably pull them by an api if needed.
exports.myFunction = onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    return myFunction(request.body, response);
});

async function myFunction({myVar1, myVar2}, response){
    let time = new Date()
    try {
        // --------------------- your code here VVV ---------------------

        // --------------------- your code here ^^^ ---------------------
        // ok responce
        response?.status(204).end()

    // all errors will be caught and posted in the google cloud log. make sure to check it after running this
    } catch (my_error) {
        // log the error, this does not need to be thrown again because this log already shows as an error
        // error() is imported from "firebase-functions/logger"
        error("update failed, myVar2: " + myVar2+ " error: " + my_error, {myVar1, myVar2, time: time.toISOString}) 
        // error response
        response?.status(500).end()
    }
}

reminder that if the error() function receives an object as the last parameter, it will add it to the log under the jsonPayload field instead of stringifying it, you can use this to add a custom field which is always true to let you filter for this error in particular, like myConditionName = true.
